# Table cells doesn't connect to outlet in iOS storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I followed [Connect outlet of a Cell Prototype in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176312/connect-outlet-of-a-cell-prototype-in-a-storyboard)

So my outlets are connected. I have this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    HomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] ;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    Group * group = [self.groups objectAtIndex: [indexPath section]];
    Friend  * friend = [[group friends ]objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@", friend.name);

    [[cell nameLabel] setText:friend.name];
    [[cell statusLabel] setText:friend.status];
    [[cell picImageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"similey.jpg"]];
    return cell;
}
```

It compiles fine but the cells show up blank with nothing in it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you changed the class of the cell in the storyboard to HomeCell? Are the data source methods being called?

Comment: Check in the debugger that the cell is the correct class and that the cell items are not nil. `NSLog(@"cell class: %@", NSStringFromClass([cell class]));`

Comment: @Zaph it shows homecell

and the class in storyboard shows HomeCell as well...

Comment: but when I do this [[cell textLabel] setText:@"hi"];

it shows hi

Comment: however it shows the HomeCell when I click on it...looks like there's some kind of overlap going on

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since HomeCell is a custom UITableViewCell it won't be in a reuse queue, so your table view will need to know about it through the registerClass method, like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   ...
   [self.tableView registerClass:[HomeCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}
```

Comment: This will not result in using the table cell from the storyboard.

Comment: this is incorrect when using prototype cells in a storyboard. See this reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503874/prototype-cell-from-storyboard-not-creating-uilabels-etc

Comment: The author is asking about setting an outlet from storyboard... You are describing how to register a class as tableview cell for a reuse identifier programatically. This is done in storyboards by setting the reuse identifier on a prototype cell.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the identifier of the cell in the storyboard to "Cell" to match your dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier call?

Interface Builder creates objects, and then allows you to replicate them. It doesn't change the definition of a class. So if you design an instance of a class in Interface Builder, you're only designing that single instance. Loading Storyboards and NIBs are mechanisms you can use to replicate that instance.

Designing an instance of a class in IB, and then later going and doing a direct alloc+init of that class will result in an instance completely independent of the one in Interface Builder.

This following line of code indicates to me that you're expecting the instance in the storyboard to have an influence on what happens when you alloc+init your class directly:

```
[[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]
```

If you're ever hitting that line, that's probably your problem. That line shouldn't be there if you created the cell in the storyboard. For cells created in the storyboard, -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: will always return an instance of the cell provided that you matched up the identifiers.