# Trying to register a nib to access my outlets from my view

Tags: ios, swift, nib

I am trying to register a "nib" but most of the answers online are talking about an .xib file, but I do not have any .xib files in my project. What should I set as my nibName to be able to reach the outlets in my cell from my TableView?

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "????", bundle: Bundle.main)
holesTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

All help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register a nib for a table view cell you must create and add a .xib file to your project. Basically `@IBOutlet` means a connection between a UI-element of .xib and source code. See further information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html)

Comment: I see. Do I really need to make a new .xib file tho and connect it that way to be able to use the outlets from my TableViewCell class in my ViewController class? since I am using a storyboard and no .xib files.

Comment: You can define a cell prototype in the storyboard. In this case you don't need to register a .xib

Comment: Yeah I have done that but I have two labels in my prototype cell and the only way I have been able to edit them is by using :   

`cell.textLabel?.text = "STRING"`  

And that only edits the first label in my cell. When I try to change "textLabel?" to the names of the label outlets in my prototype cell the cells disappear from my TableView when I run the app.  
Sorry for the complicated questions :S

Comment: @Hinni you can accept my answer and ask a question how to use outlets in .storyboard. Basically it's the same thing as in .xib see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176312/connect-outlet-of-a-cell-prototype-in-a-storyboard