# How do you access Static UItableviewcell Accessory Detail (the i button)?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

[image]
[image]

Xcode doesn't let me drag a line and connect to the code files. And do I have to create a UIView for each of the "Detail" please?

Edit: I can link the cell to the code. But I don't know how to access the Detail Accessory. You don't even see the element in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect outlet of a Cell Prototype in a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176312/connect-outlet-of-a-cell-prototype-in-a-storyboard)

Comment: Thank you the4kman. But the "i" button is generated by the editor when I selected "Detail" for accessory. I read the post but I still don't know how to access it.